# How can I compare two values at two separate locations in a Firebase Realtime Database using the security rules language?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

**I want to compare data at one node with data located at an entirely different node.**

Please know, in advance I cannot change any front end codes, by instruction of my project lead.

*Context:*
I'm building for a client which will be an upscale chatting app for people who want to find new roommates on college campuses. There are two user types, leasees (`leasee)` and leasors (`leasor`).

`leasor` users add listings and have profiles, while `leasee` users also have profiles and initiate communication by reaching out to `leasor` users first with a `roommateRequest` - it's a chat message but its basically like a Skype, Facebook or LinkedIn request if you will.

I want both user types to be able to write to or remove UIDs from the `roommates` node (their roommates list on the app), similar to a Facebook friends list. However, when a `leasee` has no `roommates` they cannot write to the `roommates` node because they send a `roommateRequest` to `leasor` users and `leasor` users cannot send a `roommateRequest` to a `leasee` user profile.

On the frontend iOS client, the `leasor` user accepts a `roommateRequest` - which simultaneously writes to both the `leasor` user's `roommates` node & the requesting `leasee` user's `roommates` node.

**Here is the front end iOS client code related to the database data I will show you next:**

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class ChatFunctionService {
    
    func sendRoommateRequestToId(text: String, _ id: String, completionHandler: @escaping() -> Void) {
        
        let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
        let expiration = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date())?.timeIntervalSince1970 else {
            return
        }
        var values: [String: Any] = ["expiration": expiration, "status": "pending"]
        values["receiverProfileType"] = otherUserTypeTextString
        
        Database.database().reference().child("roommateRequests").childByAutoId().setValue(values) { _, ref in
            
            let message = UserChatModel(
                dictionary: [
                    "text": text,
                    "senderId": uid,
                    "receiverId": id,
                    "timestamp": timestamp,
                    "roommateRequestId": ref.key!,
                    "receiverProfileType": self.otherUserTypeTextString
                ]
            )
            self.sendChat(message, toUser: id) {
                completionHandler()
            }
        }
    }
    
    ///Send message:
    private func sendChat(_ message: UserChatModel, toUser receiverId: String, completion: @escaping() -> Void) {
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
        let partnerId = message.getPartnerId() else { return }
        
        Database.database().reference().child("messages").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(message.data) { _, ref in
            
            let messageUID = ref.key!
            let senderRef = Database.database().reference().child("conversations").child(uid).child(self.userTypeTextString).child(receiverId)
            let receiverRef = Database.database().reference().child("conversations").child(receiverId).child(self.otherUserTypeTextString).child(uid)
            
            ref.updateChildValues(["uid": messageUID])
            senderRef.updateChildValues([messageUID: 1])
            receiverRef.updateChildValues([messageUID: 1])
            
            self.updateChatsData(chat: message, partnerUID: partnerId, messageUID: messageUID)
            completion()
        }
    }
    
    func acceptRoommateRequest(roommateRequestId: String, userTypeTextString: String, receiverUID: String, otherUserTypeTextString: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            completion()
            return
        }
        Database.database().reference().child("roommateRequests").child(roommateRequestId).child("status").setValue("accepted")
        
        let values = [
            "/\(uid)/\(userTypeTextString)/\(receiverUID)": 1,
            "/\(receiverUID)/\(otherUserTypeTextString)/\(uid)": 1
        ]
        Database.database().reference().child("roommates").updateChildValues(values)
        
        updateChatsMetaDataForNewRoommate(userTypeTextString: userTypeTextString, receiverUID: receiverUID, otherUserTypeTextString: otherUserTypeTextString) {
            completion()
        }
    }
    
    func updateChatsMetaDataForNewRoommate(userTypeTextString: String, receiverUID: String, otherUserTypeTextString: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void ) {
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        Database.database().reference().child("chatsData").child(uid).child(userTypeTextString).child(receiverUID).child("roommates").setValue(true)
        Database.database().reference().child("chatsData").child(receiverUID).child(otherUserTypeTextString).child(uid).child("roommates").setValue(true)
        
        sendUserChat(text: "roommate request granted.", receiverUID: receiverUID) { (messageId) in
            completion()
        }
    }
    
    func sendUserChat(text: String, receiverUID: String, completion: @escaping(String?) -> Void) {
        
        let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        var chatDictionary: [String: Any] = [
            "text": text, "timestamp": timestamp,
            "senderId": uid, "receiverId": receiverUID
        ]
        chatDictionary["receiverProfileType"] = "leasee"
        let chat = UserChatModel(dictionary: chatDictionary)
        
        guard let partnerUID = chat.getPartnerId() else {
            return
        }
        Database.database().reference().child("threads").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(chat.data) { _, ref in
            
            let messageUID = ref.key!
            ref.updateChildValues(["uid": messageUID])
            
            self.updateChatsData(
                chat: chat,
                partnerUID: partnerUID,
                messageUID: messageUID
            )
            completion(messageUID)
        }
    }
    
    func updateChatsData(chat: UserChatModel, partnerUID: String, messageUID: String) {
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
        var chatData = [String: Any]()
        
        chatData["lastMessageSenderId"] = uid
        chatData["lastMessageId"] = messageUID
        chatData["lastMessage"] = chat.text ?? ""
        chatData["chatMemberIds"] = [uid, partnerUID]
        
        Database.database().reference().child("chatsMetaData").child(uid).child(userTypeTextString).child(partnerUID).setValue(chatData)
        Database.database().reference().child("chatsMetaData").child(partnerUID).child(otherUserTypeTextString).child(uid).setValue(chatData)
    }
}

class UserChatModel {
    
    var text: String?
    var senderId: String
    var receiverId: String
    var timeStamp: NSNumber
    var data: [String: Any]
    var roommateRequestId: String?
    
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        
        data = dictionary
        text = dictionary["text"] as? String
        senderId = dictionary["senderId"] as! String
        timeStamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as! NSNumber
        receiverId = dictionary["receiverId"] as? String ?? ""
        roommateRequestId = dictionary["roommateRequestId"] as? String
        
        super.init(dictionary: dictionary)
    }
    
    func getPartnerId() -> String? {
        
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return nil
        }
        return senderId == uid ? receiverId : senderId
    }
}
```

Once the `leasee` has a single `roommate`, they should be able to remove that `roommate` from their `roommates` list (if they so wish). Continually, only `leasor` users can accept a `roommateRequest` which writes to both the `roomateRequest` sender (`leasee`) user's UID in the `roommates` node and the receiver (`leasor`) user's UID in the `roommates` node. Moreover, `leasor` users can also remove `leasee` users from their `roommates` node, at anytime.

The issue is I don't want just any user to be able to write or update the `roommates` node of any user unless it is removing themselves from it.

**Here is the full realtime-database structure for the chat portion of the app, in two screenshot images:**

[image: top three nodes]
[image: bottom two nodes]

I've narrowed my works down (between the iOS front end, database structure and security rules) to matching the `lastMessageId` value from the `chatsMetaData` or `chats` node to then check the `threads` node to get the `roommateRequestId` and then compare the `roommateRequestId` to the 'roommateRequests' node to verify that the leasor can write to the leasee's node. And then I will provide an OR case and match the value at the `roommates` node to the value of auth.uid for after they are already on each other's roommate's list for when a user wants to write to their `roommates` node (removing a roommate) - but I have no idea on how to do any of this. I know what to do but I am not sure how to achieve it...

**I think I can reference the chatsMetaData node all the way down to the 'lastMessageId' value :**
[image: lastMessageId]

**With this value I think I should then search the `threads` node to get the `roommateRequestId` and then search the `roommateRequests` node to match it and allow a write along with some `auth.uid` checks to match uid values in the node's data. But how can I do all this if they are by autoId way?**

[image]

Comment: Firebase security can never *search* across data. What they can do is access data at a known path and then read its value. I'm not sure whether that answers your question though, as I'm having a hard time translating the amount of code and data to a minimal set of rules.

Comment: Got it. That makes sense. Well, its a pretty complex application. The other really tricky part is users can delete their message data at 'chats', 'chatsMetaData' and the 'messages' nodes... I think the front end might need to be restructured. Not sure.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - notice that the first five characters of the value at the 'uid' node that's embedded at the bottom of the 'threads' node does match the first five characters of the value at 'roommateRequestId' in the same node... and the value of 'roomateRequestId' is located in the 'roommateRequests' node at the very top level. So I could say 'rommateRequests'.hasChild(?) or something?

Comment: These are all linked together in a pretty (whacky (bad) or wicked (surprisingly good) way - I just have yet to decide which lol.

Comment: This `-N...` strings look like push IDs, which means the first 8 or so characters are based on the current timestamp and that would explain why they first few characters of each of those IDs are the same.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any way to go about this you may be thinking of or should I restructure the front end? Perhaps a cloud function could intervene and update the data once it becomes available in place A and make sure it's in place B?

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)